# SQL Process string before using it as value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql.

I have a column with value that would be something like this:

```
"50 000 - 100 000 |##| 300 000 - 400 000"
```

The values could actually be turned around. For example:

```
"300 000 - 400 000 |##| 50 000 - 100 000"
```

And pretty much what to me it needs to mean is `50 000 - 400 000`.

Then I need to compare it inside sql and check if this column:

```
range_column ("50 000 - 100 000 |##| 300 000 - 400 000") < max_value AND column range_column ("50 000 - 100 000 |##| 300 000 - 400 000") > min_value.
```

Is something like this even possible?

Thanks for help

Comment: Why is your example 50,000 - 400,00 and not 300,00 - 100,000?  How do you know the range is valid?

Comment: Those are 2 different ranges. But I need to combine those ranges and that would be 50 000 - 400 000.

Comment: There could be even third range that would be 100 000 - 200 000.

Comment: These are the sort of issues you get when storing data you later want to use in some processing as a delimited list!

Comment: Well, I agree that this storing method is not the right way to go. But I am not the person who thought of it. My question is if it even is possible to achieve what I need?

Comment: It is possible, but messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the min and max values from your range for you:-

```
SELECT MIN(aValue) AS range_start,
        MAX(aValue) AS range_end
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(some_column, ' - ', ','), ' |##| ', ','), ' ', ''), ',', tens.aCnt * 10 + units.aCnt + 1), ',', -1) AS UNSIGNED) AS aValue
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
) sub0
```

This uses REPLACE to get rid of the unwanted extra formatting, and using REPLACEing spaces with commas to turn it into a comma separated list. Then cross joins this with a couple of fixed queries to get a list of values between 1 and 100, and uses that to split up the comma separated list. Results of all that is used as a sub query to use MIN and MAX on